# Forgotten password for Bitcoin core wallet

Tags: wallet

My old computer was trash my new computer btc core wallet with my private keys and password I made my backup wallet locked I forgot my password how can I find my password please help

Comment: If you forgot your password, nobody here will be able to help you (that is the point of a password!). If it was a weak password, perhaps you could use some password cracking software to attempt to guess it. If it was a proper strong password and you've forgotten it... you're probably out of luck :(

Comment: I wouldn’t delete it, perhaps one day you’ll remember the password, etc

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=forgotten+password